# converting a string of declared variables (e.g. "x+y") to a double as a mathematical function

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is read a line (string) and use it as a mathematical function to get (double) values or answers to it at different points (like a calculator basically)

I included a very simplistic code of what I'm trying to do just for the sake of being direct and straight forward:

```
double x, y, z;
String function;

x = 5;
y = 4;
function = "(x*y)+y";

z = Double.parseDouble(function);

/*
I want z to equal this
z = (x*y)+y;
*/
System.out.print("z= " + z);
```

Again, this is only a sample code to be clearer about my question. My question again is: how can I set z = function when z is a double and function is a string?

NOTE: I tried parse as you can see, but it didn't work. I also tried to read the string character by character, but it didn't work either because it added the value of the characters together.

Comment: You need to write a parser for that. Java has no `eval`...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for a [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

These are basical components of every compiler or interpreter as

- the lexer is able to split input (your string) into tokens
- the parser is able to build a tree which represent the syntatic shape of your tokens to be furtherly interpretated semantically

This discipline is quite wide and I suggest you to start with something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) for Java, it is a parser generator that will generate both lexer and parser according to rules you specify through a grammar. There are many, this is just the first that came into my mind.

If you want to forget about all this theory just embed something like JavaScript or Groovy in your Java program, they are able to interpret code that is given at runtime so that you can just go that way.

Comment: There is also parboiled. And parboiled has a working calculator example, too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have something like `eval` builtin. But you can use an expression language like [spEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html), [mvel](http://mvel.codehaus.org) or [Jexl](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/) for this.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940294/techniques-of-el-on-java) SO question can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at [Parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled). Unlike nearly all other parser solutions for Java, you write your grammars... In Java.

What is more, among the Java examples, there are [working calculators](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/tree/master/examples-java/src/main/java/org/parboiled/examples/calculators).

Answer (score 0):

```
float eval(String exp)
{
    char[] a = exp.toCharArray();
    float[] buffer = new int[exp.length];
    int k = 0;
    for(int i : a)
    { 
        if(a[i] >= 48 && a[i] <= 57) //checking for numbers
        {
             int x = a[i] - '0';
             buffer[k++] = x;
        }
        else if(a[i] == '+' || a[i] == '-' || a[i] == '*' || a[i] == '/') //checking for operands
        {
             float result;
             switch(a[i])
             {
                  case '+': result = buffer[k] + buffer[k-1]; break;       
                  case '-': result = buffer[k] - buffer[k-1]; break;
                  case '*': result = buffer[k] * buffer[k-1]; break; 
                  case '/': result = buffer[k] / buffer[k-1]; break;               
             }
        }
        buffer[k++] = result;
    }
    return buffer[k]; //finally returning the recent value
}
```

Use a method like this. Will help a lot. Implemented using a stack data structure.